# Carrierwave unique filename not being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I looked at the carrierwave wiki on github, and used the [method they describe](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files) to generate unique file names:

```
def filename
   @filename ||= "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
end

private
def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    random_token = Digest::SHA2.hexadigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{model.id.to_s}").first(20)
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, random_token)
end
```

(Using hashes though)

The problem I am having is that the filename is still being set to the original file's name. It's as if the `filename` mehod is being ignored. Not really sure what is going on. I reset the server and everything, still getting the original filename on the uploaded file and thumbnail version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the docs used `||=` operator in `filename` method, but this way the unique file name will not be set unless `@filename` is `nil`, which doesn't seem to be the usual case. Using `=` instead of `||=` (or not using assignment at all) seems to solve the issue.

```
def filename
  @filename = "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  # The following line works too
  #"#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
end
```